# Rails deployment Capistrano - capistrano/cli (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, deployment, capistrano3, rvm-capistrano

I followed this tutorial.

https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04#capistrano

Now i am stuck at this

I ran this command after set Adding The Nginx Host
cap production deploy

and ran into this, now no idea what to do.

/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- capistrano/cli (LoadError)
    from /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in`require'
    from /usr/bin/cap:3:in `'

Comment: add more logs - maybe some info before error can help

Comment: Would love to help you, but the solution I offered was deleted. I recommend making sure capistrano and all its dependencies are installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve this problem by remove old Capistrano gem.

```
# remove all old versions of the gem
gem cleanup rjb
```

I have the same error and it's because I installed this Gem and upgraded my ruby from 2.0.0 to 2.1.9. Reinstallation resolves my issue.
Hope this can help you.

If you still have this problem, I highly recommend you use bundler and

```
bundle exec cap <args>
```